# How to find employee of system user

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

I have a form that must be triggered from the `Info` class `startupPost` method, as it has to verify a condition, and if the condition is true (if it's the user's birthday), then trigger my form.
 The only way I found to verify the BDay of the user is to take it from the `EmplTable`. Also, I need to relate something between the `EmplTable` and `UserInfo` or `SysUserInfo` tables in order to give me the user ID.
 The problem is that I didn't find a proper way to relate the tables, because in my `EmplTable` I have a `DEL_userId` field wich is NOT populated and not used.
 In conclusion my `if` block from the following chunk of code does not get executed.
 Also I left The `emplTable` variable intentionally not declared, as I am not sure what's the best way to declare it.

Thanks in advance for any ideas guys!

```
void startupPost()
{
    EmplTable           emplTable     ; //intentionally left undeclared

    int                 dayOfBirth    = dayOfMth(emplTable.BirthDate);
    int                 monthOfBirth  = mthOfYr(emplTable.BirthDate);
    int                 dayOfMonth    = dayOfMth(systemdateget());
    int                 monthOfYear   = mthOfYr(systemdateget());
    str                 emplName      = emplTable.name();
    Args                args          = new Args(); //formrun
    FormRun             formrun;
    ;

    if (dayOfBirth == dayOfMonth && monthOfBirth == monthOfyear )
    {
        info("ok"); //just to verify if my loop is working
        new MenuFunction(menuitemDisplayStr(NET_PALIN_001_HBDay),   MenuItemType::Display).run();
        //        args.name(formStr(NET_PALIN_001_HBDay));
        //        formRun = classFactory.formRunClass(args);
        //        formRun.init();
        //        formrun.run();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the table `SysCompanyUserInfo` which maps system users from `UserInfo` to employees of `EmplTable`.
Below is an example to find the associated record of `EmplTable` (if it exists) for the current user

```
static void FindCurUserEmplTable(Args _args)
{
    EmplId emplId;
    EmplTable emplTable;
    ;

    emplId = EmplTable::userId2EmplId(curuserid());
    if (emplId != '')
    {
        emplTable = EmplTable::find(emplId);
        // ... your birthday logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot DAXaholic. I think the problem is that EmplId is an int of 5 characters and the UserId is a string of 5 characters(letters). 
I don't think we can parse them...

Comment: error message below:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aeq2i9yn6fn2s2l/operandtypes%20error.JPG?dl=0

Comment: You are trying to assign employee id to employees table. Please copy above code and use same.